# Does this statement talking about agriculture or resource management?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

How to simplify the last statement which highlighted of this paragraph. I'm in doubt about the meaning of the word "[husbandry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/husbandry)" in here.

> "In carriage and behaviour they are very grave and stately, like unto
>   Portuguese ; in understanding quick and apprehensive ; in design,
>   subtle and crafty ; in discourse, courteous, but full of flatteries ;
>   naturally inclined to temperance both in meat and drink, but not to
>   chastity ; **near and provident in their families, commending good
>   husbandry**."
>
> From Adam’s Peak To Elephanta : Sketches in Ceylon (1892)

Comment: From the context, the metaphorical usage seems much more likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Edwin that the context suggests that the word 'husbandry' in this passage is likely to refer to management of resources.